# MySQL select unique pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My table looks like:

```
id A  B
1  1  3
2  2  3
3  3  1
```

I want SELECT only unique AB pairs

13 is unique

23 is unique

31 not unique because pair 13 exists

Trying with `SELECT a, b FROM test GROUP BY a, b` but query return 3 pairs

Comment: If 31 and 13 are the same shouldn't neither be returned? Also what if `A` had `13` and `B` were empty, or will that not happen?

Comment: Please learn how to use proper `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT * ... GROUP BY` shouldn't have executed.

Comment: Why is 1,3 chosen in favour of 3,1?

Comment: *Trying with `SELECT * FROM test group by a, b` but query return 3 pairs* ??? Please explain how `SELECT *` from **3-column** table can return **pairs**...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` functions both in SELECT-list and GROUP BY expression :

```
SELECT least(a, b) , greatest (a,b)  
  FROM test 
 GROUP BY least(a, b) , greatest (a,b)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c9fe7e3911a387984b5c84723268856f)</kbd>

Or just use DISTINCT within the SELECT-list :

```
SELECT DISTINCT least(a, b) , greatest (a,b)  
  FROM test
```

Comment: Result is correct but work very slow then are a lot of records

Comment: This is the answer to a subtly different problem.

Comment: right @Akina , that's just my preference style, GROUP BY rather than DISTINCT for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Below query may use indices.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
  FROM test 
 WHERE a >= b
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
  FROM test t1 
 WHERE a < b
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                      FROM test t2
                     WHERE (t1.a, t1.b) = (t2.b, t2.a) )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8c6df59f0ef7c31890064f07e2d7220c)</kbd>